# A question about a limit

Tags: limits, infinitesimals

I have the next $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{f(x)-f(\frac{\pi}{4})}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}$ when the function is $$f(x)=\frac{x+\sin(x)}{\tan(x)}.$$
I don't know how to even start. I am sorry that this is short but I really don't know.

Comment: Take a look at that limit. Look at the form of it. Does it look, in any way, shape or form, familiar?

Comment: What is the definition of the derivative of a function? Any relation with your limit?

Comment: @Arthur I can't see, can you show me?

Comment: Give it a try!! What is the definition of the derivative of a function?

Comment: @RobertZ I am not good at this, therefore I asked to see how you do that. I have tried a lot of times.

Comment: You have a BIG hint. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition
Now it is your turn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is said to be differentiable at $c$, if there exists a real number $\alpha$ such that
$$f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\alpha.$$
Now see your question.

Find $f'$ and then put $x=\frac{π}{4}.$

---

Note that $\frac{d}{dx}f=f'.$
If $$f(x)=\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$$, then $$f'(x)=\frac{g(x)\frac{d}{dx}h(x)-h(x)\frac{d}{dx}g(x)}{(g(x))^2}.$$

Comment: so is it $1-\frac{\pi +\sqrt{2}}{2}$